# Can't Run MySQL on MacOS

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, xampp, mariadb

I can't run MySQL database on XAMPP. So, I tried the following command in the terminal to run MySQL

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

but, the results are like this:

[image]

Please help. I don't want to run MariaDB. Just want to run MySQL. Thank you friend!

Comment: how many mysql server installed do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You must have installed MariaDB after MySQL, this is why MariaDB replaced `mysql` command. One solution would be uninstalling MariaDB. Other, trying to revert mysql alias set by MariaDB. I am not an OSX user, but in linux you just need to edit your ~/.bashrc file and look for a line like `alias mysql...` and just delete it (or comment it).